# Parallel execution on stack/queue

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Is it possible to have stack or queue on which we do parallel execution of some function? I would like to have this possibility to use it on iterative function that does same thing but just on the subsets. For example function `f`:

```
f <- function(vec){
  if(length(vec) <= 100) return(vec)
  unname(lapply(split(vec, sample(1:3, length(vec), TRUE)), f))
}

rlang::squash_if(f(1:1000), function(x) class(x) == "list")
```

I've found only functions that run predefined for-loops in parallel but not on stack/queue.

Comment: See the parallel package.  It has a replacement for `lapply()`

Comment: Wouldn't that run in parallel only instances within one single call of function `f` ? If so then it is possible that a lot of workers are inactive (if that call has small vector)?